# custom keyboard keys looks blurry

Tags: android, keyboard, soft-keyboard, blurry

I customized the soft keyboard. But keyboard keys(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,. and OK) is looking blurry.Delete key is fine but other key is looking blurry.

Here is my keyboard.
[image]

Here is my custom keyboard xml file

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="10%p"
android:keyWidth="24%p"
android:verticalGap="0px" >

<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="49"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="1" />
    <Key
        android:codes="50"
        android:keyLabel="2" />
    <Key
        android:codes="51"
        android:keyLabel="3" />
    <Key
        android:codes="-3"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="OK"
        android:keyWidth="28%p" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="52"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="4" />
    <Key
        android:codes="53"
        android:keyLabel="5" />
    <Key
        android:codes="54"
        android:keyLabel="6" />
    <Key
        android:codes="-5"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
        android:keyWidth="28%p" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="55"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="7" />
    <Key
        android:codes="56"
        android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key
        android:codes="57"
        android:keyLabel="9" />
    <Key
        android:codes="48"
        android:keyLabel="0"
        android:keyWidth="14%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="46"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="."
        android:keyWidth="14%p" />
</Row>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 27):

Though it is very late answer, it will help others.

use either **android:shadowRadius** or **android:shadowColor** attribute in your KeyboardView tag.

ex:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

or

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowRadius="0.0"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: can you add some description about why this is happening?

Comment: @Jam, just give little more attention to understand how the shadowRadious and shadowColor is working, you can figure out the reason yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your keys are bigger than normal keyboard keys. Because of this these number keys upscaling and shows blurry i guess. You will use custom drawable images.

Comment: Thank u for ur comments but Plz check the '0' and dot keys in the uploaded image that is small but still that key looks like blurry.and i tried with small keys means i changed the width and height of keys but still problem not solve.